# show active state in label when using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have been using `redux-form` for the forms but I wanted to switch to `formik` but I could not find the way to show if my input field is active or not. Like when using `redux-form` I used to do

```
{label && (
   <Label isActive={meta !== undefined && meta.active} css={labelCss}>
    {label}
   </Label>
)}
```

but how is it possible to do in formik

Here is my code

```
const TextField = ({ label, type, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";
  console.log('meta', meta)
  return (
    <>
      <InputGroup>
        {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
        <Input type={type} {...field} {...props} />
      </InputGroup>
    </>
  );
};
```

I don't see any active props in formik.

Comment: It doesn't support by formik. You need to handle active state in your TextField state. Just play with `handleFocus ` and `handleBlur` functions to update active state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `onFocus` prop supported by input field.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

<Input
  onBlur={() => setActive(false)}
  onFocus={() => setActive(true)}

  {...otherProps}

/>
```